# How to document a dictionary in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, jsdoc

Having next example:

```js
var CONF = {
    locale: {
        "en": {
            name: "English",
            lang: "en-US"
        },
        "es": {
            name: "Spanish",
            lang: "es-ES"
        }
    }
};
```

And knowing that what the locale property contains is a dictionary object, which comes from the database, how can I document its inner properties with JSDoc?

Currently I am thinking to `typedef`  type for my locale objects, then may I be able to set the `locale` property to simply an Array of my defined type? Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

According to the [JSDoc 3 docs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html):

> Arrays and objects (type applications and record types)
>
> An object with string keys and number values:
>
> > `{Object.<string, number>}`

So it would be:

```
/** @type {{locales: Object.<string, {name: string, lang: string}>}} */
var CONF = {
    locales: {
        en: {
            name: "English",
            lang: "en-US"
        },
        es: {
            name: "Spanish",
            lang: "es-ES"
        }
    }
};
```

Cleaner, using `@typedef`

```
/**
 * @typedef {{name: string, lang: string}} Locale
 */
/**
 * @type {{locales: Object.<string, Locale>}}
 */
var CONF = {
    locales: {
        en: {
            name: "English",
            lang: "en-US"
        },
        es: {
            name: "Spanish",
            lang: "es-ES"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the double curly braces?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa that's an object within a curly brace.

Comment: Yes I found that out... VS Code syntax highlighting FTW

Comment: Any idea how to change the name of the `string` in `Object.<string, locale>` from `x` to something else?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell:

Using `@typedef` and `@property` to define a custom type is the "correct" way in JSDoc. But it is cumbersome to write and ugly to read (a cardinal sin in documentation).

The record type is much neater (note the double `{{`s):

```
   /** {{
         name:string, 
         lang:string
   }} */
```

Comment: Hmmm... this documents a singe entry in the locale object, am I wrong?  BTW that comment [doesn't validate](http://orgachem.github.io/jsdoctypeparser/) because of the lang description, you should remove it ;)

Comment: You're not wrong! I thought that was the most useful snippet to give you, since the locale var is a map of custom-type locale objects.

Comment: If the Dictionary is based on array it can be {Array<{key:string, value:{name:string, lang:string}}>} or {{key:string, value:{name:string, lang:string}}[]}... still object are tend to be dictionary of key values in java-script, and in my case, and ÁxelCostasPena scenario, i rather like to go with ÁxelCostasPena solution.